# VBA shell script set environment variable before execution

Tags: python, vba, shell, ipython

I'm trying to run a VBA module that uses a shell script to run an ipython notebook (using runipy) before going on to do other things, but my ipython notebook script requires inputs, which are setup using environment variables.

Here's the VBA I have so far:

```
rundate = Range("b1").Value
shellScript = "runipy C:\argstest.ipynb"

Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

Set wshSystemEnv = wsh.Environment("SYSTEM")
wshSystemEnv("CURRWK") = rundate
```

If I then run:

```
MsgBox (wshSystemEnv("CURRWK"))
```

The result is correct:

```
2015-04-17
```

However, if I continue on and exec my shellscript, it isn't recognizing this variable

```
Set WshShellExec = wsh.exec(shellScript)
Range("a1").Value = WshShellExec.StdErr.ReadAll
```

shows me that when python runs it gets a key error:

```
KeyError: 'CURRWK'
```

If I remove the VBA and run this straight from the command line, I would do it like this:

```
set CURRWK=2015-04-17
runipy C:\Python27\Programs\ipython\ACT\argstest.ipynb
```

How do I get the shell created in the VBA to create the new environment variable so the python script can see it when it executes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `Process` instead of `SYSTEM`? Your VBA may not have the rights to modify the system-level variables. ("But it can read it back after setting it," you say. True, but your script may have registry virtualization enabled.) Process most closely emulates the command line `SET` statement in that the change is only for the current process and child processes and is not persisted.